# How can I get the duration of a video?

Tags: wpf, video

Using WPF, how can I get the duration of a video in a .wmv file?

Comment: WPF is a GUI. Which language are you referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Retreiving the duration of a WMV in C#](http://johndyer.name/post/Retreiving-the-duration-of-a-WMV-in-C.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [`MediaElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx) you can use [`MediaElement.NaturalDuration` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.naturalduration.aspx).